# How to obtain a large profile image from Google Plus?

Tags: google-api, google-plus

I tried:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/userid/?fields=image&sz=500&access_token=token
```

But it only returns a regular size image.

```
"image": {
  "url": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-hSREIXMA6Lg/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAEU/YJ2222HnViD2/photo.jpg?sz=50",
  "isDefault": false
 }
```

I am wondering how to get a larger profile image.

Thanks

Derek

Comment: I believe you have to replace the sz=50 in the image URL you got back with the max size you want. But I'm not sure so not posting as an answer.

Comment: @Steve, You are right. Please post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to replace the `sz=50` in the image URL you got back with the max size you want.